# Manage permissions "The list view you requested was deleted, or you don't have permission to view it."

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, scratch-org

I'm using a Scratch org and trying to assign a Permission Set to a User. I go to "Setup" > "Permission Set" > Select a permission set > "Manage Assignments" > "Add Assignment" and I get the following error: *The list view you requested was deleted, or you don't have permission to view it.*"

[image]

This happens for all the Permission sets in the Scratch Org (even for the pre-defined ones). I've tried:

- Pre-defined permission sets
- Permission sets from a managed package
- Creating a brand new permission set
- Permission sets with License/No License

and it fails in all cases. When I click on the "Select a List View" dropdown, it appears empty.

This happens with a user with "System Administrator" profile, which has the: "Manage Users", "Create and Customize List Views" and "Manage Public List Views" permissions enabled.

To build the scratch org (I already tested recreating it) I've used the following command:

`sfdx org create scratch -d -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a testPermBug -v devHub -y 30 --no-namespace`

And my `config/project-scratch-def.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "orgName": "Scratch Org",
  "country": "US",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "hasSampleData": false,
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, I can assign the permission set if I go to a particular user and grant it the permission set there, or directly using `sfdx`. IMO it looks like there is something off with the Users List View, but as I previously mentioned all the permissions seem to look fine.

Comment: also running into this issue... any resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing yet